# Javascript MIME Type not Set Properly

Tags: javascript, html, mime-types

I'm building some web apps with Python/Tornado.

Some of my (HTML) pages have:

```
<script src="/static/some_script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When I load the page in FireFox, I get the warning:

> "The script from “http://localhost:8086/static/some_script.js” was
> loaded even though its MIME type (“text/plain”) is not a valid
> JavaScript MIME type."

Why does the browser think the MIME type is "text/plain" instead of "text/javascript"? Where is it getting that idea from....?

I also load:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/0.9.16/socket.io.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

for which I don't get the same warning.....

Comment: "text/javascript" seems to be obsolete in favor of application/javascript. src: http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml .

Comment: I ran across that somewhere as well and will likely make that modification.

Still, the MIME type is not being registered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Mime type is something the server send as header detail and it's *usually* based on file extension, but it can be enforced as needed.

If you run your Web page/application locally, you need to spin a webserver for that folder, as opening the `.html` file directly will not work, or better, requested files will not be served with the correct mime type.

Use a webserver, and you'll never see this error again.

Comment: yeah, then visit the *localhost* with the right port, don't open files with your browser. **Every** webserver to date serve properly JavaScript, no way python doesn't do that.

Comment: I am using the localhost URL and port. I am not opening files directly.

Comment: then it's very possible the server replies with a default page, instead of a 404, when the script (file) is not found. I don't see any possible issues.

Comment: The script (file) is being found......it's just the MIME type is wrong. 

I thought I had set it, but apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but with ExpressJS application. For me, path to the concerned static file was not correct. So exressjs(web server) defaulted to text/html mime type.

so check if "/static/some_script.js" path is correctly directing to the static file (some_script.js)

Comment: Can I assume that since the script is loading that the path is correct..?

Comment: Since the javascript is loading, I am assuming the path is correct.......

I am not getting errors that script is not found. I am getting errors that it is being identified as the wrong MIME type.....